# How to add chars to a char

Tags: c, macos, char

I am doing:

```
FILE *in;
extern FILE *popen();
char buff[512];

if (!(in = popen("df / | tail -n +2 | awk '{ print $1 }'", "r"))) {
    exit(1);
}

while (fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), in) != NULL ) {
    printf("Output: %s", buff);
}
```

So once I have `buff` how do I append additional chars, like `s0` to the end so that I can pass this `char` to a function to work with it?

Comment: since you are using c++, try ``std::string`` and ``string::c_str()`` from ``string`` to ``char *``. for ``string``, you could simple use ``+`` to append ``char``

Comment: He is using C, not C++.

Comment: @JohnnyMnemonic title says cpp

Comment: Please correct tags as it is unclear if the language is C or C++ (no need to state language in question title, that is what the tags are for).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `strcat()` to append chars to string if, of course your buffer is big enough. If it's not you must allocate more memory.

See here for example: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcat/

Answer (score 0):

You cannot append anything to `buff`, because you would write to memory that does not belong to you. You have to allocate memory on the heap and copy `buff` to that memory. Make sure to allocate enough memory that you can actually append something.

Note that if the `fgets` call did not use the whole 512 chars, you can call use `strlen(buff)` to check how many characters where read and subsequently write to `buff + strlen(buff)`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could do the trick:

```
char buff[512];
size_t pos = 0;
...
while (fgets(buff + pos, sizeof(buff) - pos, in) != NULL) {
    printf("Output: %s\n", buff + pos);
    pos += strlen(buff + pos);
}
```

If you then want to add characters not from the file, you can extend the idea:

```
strcpy(buff + pos, "s0");
pos += strlen(buff + pos);
```

or

```
buf[pos++] = 's';
buf[pos++] = '0';
buf[pos++] = '\0';
```

You have to make sure the buffer doesn't overflow.

Comment: Can i ask, how does one, after they have this char take off the \n after creating a string. Say `std::string n = string(buff)` wouldn't there be a `\n` on the end the resulting string?

Comment: There are functions for insertion and deletion in `std::string`. See documentation.

Answer (score 0):

For a very c++ way of doing it:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
int main() {
  FILE *in;
  char buff[512];
  if (!(in = popen("df /", "r"))) {
    return 1;
  }
  fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), in); //discard first line
  while (fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), in) != NULL ) {
    std::istringstream line(buff);
    std::string s;
    line >> s; // extract first word
    s += "s0"; // append something
    std::cout << s << '\n';
  }
  return 0;
}
```

The original title specified c++.  For editing strings, I recommend C++ over C, unless you want to over-optimize.